# How to use T-SQL XML modify('replace value of ...)' to search/replace blank attributes

Tags: sql-server, xml, string, replace

This is a two-part problem.  I have a table with an XML column containing component & attribute data for parts. One of the attributes needs to be updated across all components and attributes in all records. 
I found a partial solution using technique from the below Technet article:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/28601.t-sql-tips-search-and-replace-string-from-multiple-nodes-within-a-xml-document.aspx
Where it falls short:

1. In cases where the PrintCode is an empty string (PrintCode="") the approach fails, leaving the original empty string instead of replacing it with a value of "I". This is because the contains() function always returns TRUE when $arg2 is a zero-length string.
2. The WHILE EXISTS loop works to remap only one "old" value to one "New" value. I was hoping to be able to leverage the mapping table and updated all attributes in one pass.
   I've tried a few other approaches, but have not come up with a single-pass solution.

This is a simplified form of the data. In reality there are many more entries that need to be remapped.

I do have the brute force version working for remapping all values except for the zero-length string, but again would rather perform all of the updates in one statement if possible.

Example code:

```
    DECLARE @Map TABLE ([Old] VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL, [New] VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL)
insert @Map ([Old], [New])
Values   ('D', 'E'),('3', 'I'),('', 'I');

DECLARE  @ConfigMaster TABLE (
    [ConfigCode] [nvarchar](15) NOT NULL,
    [ConfigMaster] [xml] NOT NULL
    )
INSERT @configMaster (ConfigCode, [ConfigMaster])
values('TestPart01', '<ConfigMaster xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Components>
    <Component Name="FRSTK">
      <Attributes>
        <Attribute Name="O-FLGOPT" Value="N" OptionListId="YES_NO" PrintCode="3" DataEntryOrder="22" />
        <Attribute Name="O-GRDLGT" Value="0" OptionListId="" PrintCode="" DataEntryOrder="0" />
        <Attribute Name="O-LEADLG" Value="72" OptionListId="" PrintCode="D" DataEntryOrder="4" />
        <Attribute Name="O-LEADTP" Value="R" OptionListId="1F3" PrintCode="D" DataEntryOrder="3" />
        <Attribute Name="O-LOCOPT" Value="N" OptionListId="YES_NO" PrintCode="3" DataEntryOrder="24" />
        <Attribute Name="O-CODE" Value="N18A13" OptionListId="1F1" PrintCode="D" DataEntryOrder="1" />
        <Attribute Name="O-CONOPT" Value="N" OptionListId="YES_NO" PrintCode="3" DataEntryOrder="25" />
        <Attribute Name="O-FITOPT" Value="Y" OptionListId="YES_NO" PrintCode="3" DataEntryOrder="23" />
        <Attribute Name="O-FITTIN" Value="BG" OptionListId="1F5" PrintCode="D" DataEntryOrder="32" />
        <Attribute Name="O-FLANGE" Value="" OptionListId="1F2" PrintCode="" DataEntryOrder="0" />
      </Attributes>
    </Component>
  </Components>
</ConfigMaster>')
select * from @ConfigMaster; --before

WHILE EXISTS
(
SELECT  *
        FROM    @ConfigMaster
        WHERE   ConfigMaster.exist('//Component/Attributes/Attribute[ contains(@PrintCode, "D")]') = 1
)
BEGIN
         UPDATE [m]
         SET ConfigMaster.modify('replace value of 
                                    (//Component/Attributes/Attribute[ contains(@PrintCode , "D")]/@PrintCode)[1] 
                                  with sql:column("New") ')
         FROM
         (
              SELECT  ConfigMaster,
                        t.u.value('./@PrintCode[1]','varchar(1)') AS OrigValue
              FROM    @ConfigMaster as [p]
              CROSS APPLY p.ConfigMaster.nodes('/ConfigMaster/Components/Component/Attributes/Attribute[ contains(@PrintCode , "D")]') as t(u)
         ) as [m]
         Inner join @Map as s on s.Old = m.OrigValue

END
select * from @ConfigMaster --after pass 1: "D" updated to "E"
WHILE EXISTS
(
SELECT  *
        FROM    @ConfigMaster
        WHERE   ConfigMaster.exist('//Component/Attributes/Attribute[ contains(@PrintCode, "3")]') = 1
)
BEGIN
         UPDATE [m]
         SET ConfigMaster.modify('replace value of (//Component/Attributes/Attribute[ contains(@PrintCode , "3")]/@PrintCode)[1] with sql:column("New") ')
         FROM
         (
              SELECT  ConfigMaster,
                        t.u.value('./@PrintCode[1]','varchar(1)') AS OrigValue
              FROM    @ConfigMaster as [p]
              CROSS APPLY p.ConfigMaster.nodes('/ConfigMaster/Components/Component/Attributes/Attribute[ contains(@PrintCode , "3")]') as t(u)
         ) as [m]
         Inner join @Map as s on s.Old = m.OrigValue

END
select * from @ConfigMaster --after pass 2: "3" updated to "I"
WHILE EXISTS
(
SELECT  *
        FROM    @ConfigMaster
        WHERE   ConfigMaster.exist('//Component/Attributes/Attribute[contains(@PrintCode , "")]') = 1 --the empty string "" has special meaning to the contains() function
)
BEGIN
         UPDATE [m]
         SET ConfigMaster.modify('replace value of (//Component/Attributes/Attribute[ contains(@PrintCode , "")]/@PrintCode)[1] with sql:column("New") ')
         FROM
         (
              SELECT  ConfigMaster,
                        t.u.value('./@PrintCode[1]','varchar(1)') AS OrigValue
              FROM    @ConfigMaster as [p]
              CROSS APPLY p.ConfigMaster.nodes('/ConfigMaster/Components/Component/Attributes/Attribute[ contains(@PrintCode , "")]') as t(u)
         ) as [m]
         Inner join @Map as s on s.Old = isnull(m.OrigValue,'')
      break --this will not exit otherwise...                 
END
select * from @ConfigMaster --after pass 3: no change
```

Thanks in advance!

Clayton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hate loops in SQL-Server... Sometimes we cannot avoid it, but in most cases there are other approaches and in most cases these set-based approaches are better:

You do not seem to need the namespaces declared so I let them away...

I reduced this a bit, so it might not fully keep up with your needs. Let me know, if something is missing:

```
DECLARE  @ConfigMaster TABLE (
    [ConfigCode] [nvarchar](15) NOT NULL,
    [ConfigMaster] [xml] NOT NULL
    )
INSERT @configMaster (ConfigCode, [ConfigMaster])
values('TestPart01', '<ConfigMaster xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Components>
    <Component Name="FRSTK">
      <Attributes>
        <Attribute Name="O-FLGOPT" Value="N" OptionListId="YES_NO" PrintCode="3" DataEntryOrder="22" />
        <Attribute Name="O-GRDLGT" Value="0" OptionListId="" PrintCode="" DataEntryOrder="0" />
        <Attribute Name="O-LEADLG" Value="72" OptionListId="" PrintCode="D" DataEntryOrder="4" />
        <Attribute Name="O-LEADTP" Value="R" OptionListId="1F3" PrintCode="D" DataEntryOrder="3" />
        <Attribute Name="O-LOCOPT" Value="N" OptionListId="YES_NO" PrintCode="3" DataEntryOrder="24" />
        <Attribute Name="O-CODE" Value="N18A13" OptionListId="1F1" PrintCode="D" DataEntryOrder="1" />
        <Attribute Name="O-CONOPT" Value="N" OptionListId="YES_NO" PrintCode="3" DataEntryOrder="25" />
        <Attribute Name="O-FITOPT" Value="Y" OptionListId="YES_NO" PrintCode="3" DataEntryOrder="23" />
        <Attribute Name="O-FITTIN" Value="BG" OptionListId="1F5" PrintCode="D" DataEntryOrder="32" />
        <Attribute Name="O-FLANGE" Value="" OptionListId="1F2" PrintCode="" DataEntryOrder="0" />
      </Attributes>
    </Component>
  </Components>
</ConfigMaster>')
select * from @ConfigMaster; --before
```

--ugly brute force, but *easy-cheesy-one-line*...

```
UPDATE @ConfigMaster SET ConfigMaster=
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CAST(ConfigMaster AS NVARCHAR(MAX)),' PrintCode="D"',' PrintCode="E"'),' PrintCode="3"',' PrintCode="I"'),' PrintCode=""',' PrintCode="I"');
```

--XQuery, if the limitations are okay for you (assuming there might be more then one `<Component>`):

```
UPDATE @ConfigMaster SET ConfigMaster=
ConfigMaster.query
(N' 
  <ConfigMaster>
    <Components>
    {
        for $comp in //ConfigMaster/Components/Component
        return
        <Component>{$comp/@Name}
        <Attributes>
        {
            for $node in $comp/Attributes/Attribute
            return
            <Attribute>
            {
                for $attr in $node/@*
                return
                if(local-name($attr)!="PrintCode") then 
                    $attr
                else
                    attribute PrintCode {if($attr="D") then "E" else "I"}
            }
            </Attribute>
        }
        </Attributes>
        </Component>
    }
    </Components>
    </ConfigMaster>
');
```

--and finally *de-composition / re-composition* (assuming there might be several components)

```
WITH comp AS
(
    SELECT comp.value(N'@Name',N'nvarchar(max)') AS ComponentName
          ,comp.query(N'*') AS Children
    FROM @ConfigMaster 
    CROSS APPLY ConfigMaster.nodes(N'/ConfigMaster/Components/Component') A(comp)
)
SELECT ComponentName AS [ComponentName/@Name]
      ,(
        SELECT attr.value(N'@Name',N'nvarchar(max)') AS [@Name]
              ,attr.value(N'@Value',N'nvarchar(max)') AS [@Value]
              ,attr.value(N'@OptionListId',N'nvarchar(max)') AS [@OptionListId]
              ,CASE attr.value(N'@PrintCode',N'nvarchar(max)') WHEN 'D' THEN 'E' ELSE 'I' END AS [@PrintCode]
              ,attr.value(N'@DataEntryOrder',N'nvarchar(max)') AS [@DataEntryOrde]
        FROM Children.nodes(N'Attributes/Attribute') A(attr)
        FOR XML PATH('Attribute'),ROOT('Attributes'),TYPE     
       )
FROM comp
FOR XML PATH('Components'),ROOT('ConfigMaster')
```

Comment: Thank you for the most thorough and excellent response!  I had already discarded the brute force update approach because it could lead to truncation of the XML. I tested the XQuery approach on a document with multiple components, and it updated everything correctly.  I did make one change to handle the more complex remapping. I used the 'or' operator inside the if(). I'll update your example in case it is helpful to anyone else learning XQuery.